# Strange behavior with C# MVC db-context and updated values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I can't get my head around this...

1. I retrive an "Inventory" object.
2. I update the PackageId-value
3. I save the changes to the DB

If CurrentPackageId is not null or empty, I fetch any object with the same "CurrentPackageId" and place them in a  in the  Inventory.PackageItems.

**Here is the thing:** If I just use the "Take(1) version (commented)" I get what I expect, the JSON data outputs the Inventory object along with the PackageItems list. -fine!

But when I try to select using the CurrentPackageId variable, the JSON output contains no PackageItems.
If I place a breakpoint after SaveChanges() I can verify that the row has been updated in the DB, and If i step to the Return-line I can see that there is Indeed an object in the PackageItems, but it seem to disaper when being output.

What's going on?

```
public  ActionResult GetInventoryInfo(string pAssettId, string GivenRoomName, string CurrentPackageId)
{
    var Inventory =  _context.Inventory.Where(p => p.AssetId == pAssettId).FirstOrDefault();

    //save reference to current package 
    Inventory.PackageId = CurrentPackageId;

    _context.Update(Inventory);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentPackageId)) {
        Inventory.PackageItems = _context.Inventory.Where(p => p.PackageId == CurrentPackageId).ToList();
                 
        //Inventory.PackageItems = _context.Inventory.Take(1).ToList(); 
    }

    return Json(Inventory);
}
```

Core 3.1

I can se no reason for the code to give me the correct JSON in one case, just depending on my selection.

Comment: `_context.Update(Inventory);` - remove this line

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help

Comment: It wasn't supposed to help. I just pointed out a meaningless piece of code.

Comment: Try this method : **AsNoTracking()** , 
_context.Inventory.Where(p => p.AssetId == pAssettId).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Same result. I don't understand why it works when I include any other row: [Inventory.PackageItems = _context.Inventory.Take(1).ToList(); ] as long as it's not the same that I retrived in the first query.

Comment: Did you check your **DI** ? , I mean for example you used _AddTransient_ instead of _AddScoped_ .

Answer (score 0):

Try the Include;

```
Inventory.PackageItems = _context.Inventory.Include(p=>p.PackageItems).Where(p => p.PackageId == CurrentPackageId).ToList();
```